# Client side and server side error message display for AngularJs Form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to display different messages for client side validation error such as required message (`This Field is Required`) and server side error message which comes from backend such as (`Entered Password is incorrect`).

What I am doing now -
In `myController.js` : I am setting `$scope.message = "This Field is Required";`when user does not give any value and try to submit, the above error getting displayed.

But once he gives the value it goes to the server to check whether its valid and server returns another error message i.e `Entered Password is incorrect` as response if its not valid.

So if I set this response value to my `$scope.message`, it overrides the previous value and displays correctly, but my issue is once again if user tries to submit with blank value the overridden error message is getting displayed. But here it should display the required message i.e. `This Field is Required`.

How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom Angular Directive which validates password on the server. If any error, add the error in the `$validators` pipeline.

Example: Create a directive to check username availability

```
ngModule.directive('usernameAvailableValidator', ['$http', function($http) {
  return {
    require : 'ngModel',
    link : function($scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$asyncValidators.usernameAvailable = function(username) {
        return $http.get('/api/username-exists?u='+ username);
      };
    }
  }
}])
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
<!-- 
  first the required, pattern and minlength validators are executed
  and then the asynchronous username validator is triggered...
-->
<input type="text"
       class="input"
       name="username"
       minlength="4"
       maxlength="15"
       ng-model="form.data.username"
       pattern="^[-\w]+$"
       username-available-validator
       placeholder="Choose a username for yourself"
       required />
<div ng-if="myForm.colorCode.$error.usernameAvailable">Error Message HERE!</div>
</form>
```

Comment: But I want to do validation and http request after user clicks on submit. How it would help me?

Comment: For that, wrap your call to network inside a service/factory. When user clicks the submit button, catch the (bool) result in a variable [$scope.usernameAvailable = ***result of API***]. Then inside html template, switch ng-if="myForm.colorCode.$error.usernameAvailable" with ng-if="usernameAvailable".

Comment: Still I am not clear. Can you please explain with example.? 
I am new to Angular. There are a lot of unknowns for me :(